# Java Rectangles and Casting

Tags: java, methods, casting

Obviously based on the class assignment this is homework..so help me as much as you can/want, don't flame me for posting HW okay?

I have been dying, reading through my book, reading through online for the past two hours and can't find for the love of god WHY this stupid rectangle says "Cannot find Method setX()". Also is there a way to make the doubles, be ints without casting them as int? It looks really messy, and we aren't supposed to add anything except in the method enclosing...I think I have to cast??

Thanks for any help you can give..

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Homework18A 
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      ArrayList<Rectangle> test = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
      test.add(new Rectangle(10, 20, 30, 40));
      test.add(new Rectangle(20, 10, 30, 40));
      test.add(new Rectangle(10, 20, 40, 50));
      test.add(new Rectangle(20, 10, 50, 30));
      Rectangle enc = enclosing(test);
      System.out.println(enc);
      System.out.println("Expected: java.awt.Rectangle[x=10,y=10,width=60,height=60]");
   }

   /**
      Computes the smallest rectangle enclosing all rectangles in 
      an array list.
      @param rects an array list of rectangles of size >= 1
      @return the smallest rectangle enclosing all rectangles in rect
   */
   public static Rectangle enclosing(ArrayList<Rectangle> rects)
   {
      Rectangle containRec = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
      for(int i = 0; i < rects.size(); i++) {
                if(rects.get(i).getX() < containRec.getX())
                    containRec.setX((int)rects.get(i).getX());
                if(rects.get(i).getY() < containRec.getY())
                    containRec.setY((int)rects.get(i).getY());
                if(rects.get(i).getX() + rects.get(i).getWidth() > containRec.getWidth())
                    containRec.setWidth(((int)rects.get(i).getX() + rects.get(i).getWidth()));
                if(rects.get(i).getY() + rects.get(i).getHeight() > containRec.getHeight())
                    containRec.setHeight(((int)rects.get(i).getY() + rects.get(i).getHeight()));
      }
      return containRec;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because Rectangle does not have a method `setX()` or `setY()`. If you're trying to set the position you want to use `setLocation(x,y)`.

Edit: there is no setWidth() or setHeight() methods either, you want to use setSize(width, height). Even though the Rectangle class has fields for x, y, width, and height it does not follow the normal Java conventions where the fields are made private and public getter and setter methods are used. In this case you could access the fields directly and just say `containRec.x = whatever`, but it's a bad habit to get in to.

You don't want to remove the (int) casts, but you can definitely clean up that section. Instead of calling rects.get(i) you could put a line at the beginning of the loop that says Rectangle `currentRect = rects.get(i);` or better yet use a for-each loop.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but I had to lauch :D
Poor Matt :-*
Here is the link for the api: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html

There is no setX() or setY()

Comment: Lol okay, I think I'm making this problem more complicated than it really is :( I have set some stuff but now get warnings...too many castings ~_~.....freaking rectangle problems that are absolutely useleess....

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using the `java.awt.Rectangle` class. It does not have a `setX` method (take a look at the Javadocs to confirm this), but it *does* declare it's `x` field to be public, so you can just set it directly:

```
containRec.x = whatever;
```

The same goes for `y`, of course. Directly setting public fields is generally A Bad Thing (as @Jordan Bently pointed out), but it'll work in this case.

Or you can use some combination of `setLocation`, `setBounds`, `setSize`, `setRect` or `setFrame`.

EDIT: You can get rid of all those nasty casts by using entirely integer arithmetic. Instead of using `getX()`, which returns a `double`, just look up the `x` field directly - it's an `int`.

The `java.awt.Rectangle` class is somewhat cumbersome to use.